# What could be stopping my update route not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

My node app now works smoothly but whenever I make a put request to update a post, it doesn't update.

here is what the route looks like:

I'll really appreciate your answers.

after renaming the identifier "post" it seems better but still not updating the edited posts.

The updated the code:

````
router.put('/:id', middleware.checkPostOwnership,async (req,res)=>{  
    try{
        let found_post = await post.findById(req.params.id).lean()

        if(!found_post){
            return res.send('error')
        }
        if(String(found_post.postedBy.id) !== String(req.user._id)){
            console.log('erroruser')
            res.redirect('/posts')
        }else{
            found_post = await post.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.params.id }, req.body, {
                    new:true,
                    runValidators:true
                }
            )
            console.log('update successful')
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        return res.redirect('/posts')
    }

})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are reassigning `post`. Use another name. I'm sure it's throwing "identifier `post` has already been declared" error.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion.

after renaming the identifier "post" it seems better as it now logs "update successful" but still not updating the edited posts.

Comment: Try using `findByIdAndUpdate` instead?

Comment: Thanks a lot expressjs123! Can't appreciate you enough. Now it works perfectly! Anyway to upvote your response?

Comment: You can accept it as the answer by clicking the tick.

Comment: Just did that. Thanks!